# XAML Menuitem Visibility Bound to another control or trigger isn't working

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, visibility

`Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility, ElementName=btnUndo}"/>`

I am trying to bind a menuitems visibility to another controls visibility (btnUndo).

That controls visibility is bound to a trigger

```
        <Style x:Key="undoStyle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.isEdited, ElementName=lvBatches}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.isEdited, ElementName=lvBatches}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

I tried binding the MenuItem to the same trigger, but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a `ContextMenu` or a regular `Menu`? I believe ContextMenus exist in the adorner layer, which is a different visual tree than the rest of the controls

Comment: ContextMenu - something tells me my XAML noobiness is gonna bite me again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContextMenus` exist in the Adorner Layer, which is not the same Visual Tree as the UI layer.

I know you can bind something like the following in a `MenuItem`, which will return the `Control` the `ContextMenu` is attached to, and from there you might be able to find the data you're looking for.

```
{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource=
     {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}
```

For example, you could create a Converter which traverses up the `VisualTree` from the specified control until it finds the object it's looking for, or you could bind to the DataContext and look for a specific value within your ViewModel.